# htaccess RewriteRule leading slash?

Tags: .htaccess

Does anyone have an explanation why htaccess RewriteRules does not have to use a leading slash in the first statement and a leading slash in the second statement?
Leading slash are recognized in the RewriteConds.

example

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "^/images/(.*)_thumb\.jpg" [NC]
RewriteRule "^images/(.*)_thumb\.jpg$" "/imgthumbs/$1-thumb.jpg" [R=301,QSD,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation explains this, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule:

> What is matched?
>
> In VirtualHost context, The Pattern will initially be matched against the part of the URL after the hostname and port, and before the query string (e.g. "/app1/index.html").
>
> In Directory and htaccess context, the Pattern will initially be matched against the filesystem path, **after removing the prefix that led the server to the current RewriteRule** (e.g. "app1/index.html" or "index.html" depending on where the directives are defined).

I highlighted the relevant part here.

So if you requested `http://example.com/foobar/baz.htm`, and your .htaccess file is located inside the `foobar` folder  - then the path RewriteRule matches against will only be `baz.htm`, because `/foobar/` is the path that lead the server to that rule (the place where it was configured) in the first place.

Also says this a bit further down,

> The removed prefix always ends with a slash, meaning the matching occurs against a string which never has a leading slash. Therefore, a Pattern with ^/ never matches in per-directory context.

Explaining why in the above example, `/foobar/` is stripped off the path, and not just `/foobar`.

> Leading slash are recognized in the RewriteConds.

That’s because there you are using the variable `%{REQUEST_URI}` – that is (same documentation page, a bit further up),

> The path component of the requested URI, such as "/index.html".

That variable is based on the original request, and does not change internally during the rewrite process (as the “path” segment of the *current* internal URL might.)

Comment: Thanks CBroe. One question forgotten: Why "a leading slash in the second statement" (RewriteRule replacement)?

Comment: That can be a “full” relative URL starting from the domain root again, resp. from the configured RewriteBase path.